# graphdb reasoning classify individual based on value range

Tags: owl, protege, graphdb, hermit

I am trying to use the GraphDB free version 9.5.1 to classify individuals according value ranges. But, despite using the OWL-RL reasoner, I am not getting the expected results.

I have set up a simple ontology with three classes. A `person` class, with two subclasses: `newborn` and child.

```
- person
  - newborn
  - child
```

The ontology has one data property `age`. A `newborn` is defined as (i.e., equivalent to) a person with `age value 0`, and a child is defined as a person with `age > 0`. Here is the OWL in Manchester syntax:

```
Class: person-test:person

Class: person-test:newborn
   EquivalentTo: 
        person-test:person
         and (person-test:age value 0)

Class: person-test:child
    EquivalentTo: 
        person-test:person
         and (person-test:age some xsd:integer[> 0])

DataProperty: person-test:age
```

To test the reasoning, I have defined two individuals:

- `person0` with an age of 0
- `person1` with an age > 1

Here is the OWL:

```
Individual: person-test:person0

    Types: 
        person-test:person
    
    Facts:  
     person-test:age  0

Individual: person-test:person1

    Types: 
        person-test:person
    
    Facts:  
     person-test:age  1
```

Using Protege, I am able to run the HeremiT reasoner and attain the expected results:

- `person0` is classified as a `newborn`
- `person1` is classified as a `child`

However, when I load the ontology into GraphDB using OWL-RL reasoning, the results are different: `person1` is **not** classified as a `child`, but `person0` is classified as a `newborn`.

Do the GraphDB reasoners work with value ranges, such as `xsd:integer[> 0]`?

Thanks!

Comment: see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL_2, especially `EquivalentClasses` which is made of multiple `equivClassExpression` which itself are defined as `equivClassExpression :=
    Class other than owl:Thing |
    equivObjectIntersectionOf |
    ObjectHasValue |
    DataHasValue` - long story short, `person0` works because `DataHasValue` is supported by OWL RL in equivalent class axioms, `DataSomeValuesFrom` on the other hand is not

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser. I was not aware that `DataSomeValuesFrom` is not supported by OWL2-RL.